# How does this simple redux XSS vulnerability work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I understand how XSS works on a basic conceptual level. However, I don't understand yet how a basic redux vulnerability I read about happens ([link](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/3-security-pitfalls-every-react-developer-should-know-c04715b876b5)). This link is about "3 Security Pitfalls Every React Developer Should Know", and the first one is "Server-Side Rendering Attacker-Controlled Initial State".

There it says:

> Sometimes when we render initial state, we dangerously generate a
> document variable from a JSON string. Vulnerable code looks like this:
>
> `<script>window.__STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify({ data })}</script>`
>
> This is risky because JSON.stringify() will blindly turn any data you give it into a string (so long as it is valid JSON) which will be rendered in the page. If { data } has fields that un-trusted users can edit like usernames or bios, they can inject something like this:
> `{ username: "pwned", bio: "</script><script>alert('XSS Vulnerability!')</script>" }`

I understand that XSS happens when the server fails to sanitize malicious inputs (for example script tags with malicious JS) coming from the frontend, and serves these scripts to victims which then execute the scripts within same origin as their request.

But in this case, how would this `data` value be under control of anything on the client side? It is initial state, isn't this just determined on the backend when server-side rendering?

Also, does this pitfall exist for non-server-rendered React apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When server rendering your backend may pre-load some data to pass to the client immediately. This data could be content that the user generated. In the example the user saved

```
</script><script>alert('XSS Vulnerability!')</script>
```

as part of their bio. Could be anything else: if you are building a blog platform, then you probably let your users write articles. That's your `data`. It's data that you load in your backend application and then you inject into the html of your page. Depending on how you inject this data, you may have a problem on your hands.

If you are serving a page that list all the bios of your users, and you fetch this data in the backend, *and* then you inject this data with

```
window.__STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify({ data })}
```

then you have the problem described in the article.
Your html markup may look like:

```
<script>window.__STATE__ = { username: "pwned", bio: "</script><script>alert('XSS Vulnerability!')</script>" }</script>
```

which execute `<script>alert('XSS Vulnerability!')</script>` as plain javascript.